# Constraints set up to many containers

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, constraints, autolayout

I have this VC:

[image]

My goal is:

- 2 big containers up should change size for 3.5 inch display
- 4 little ones should have pin size
- bottom one should be always in bottom.

What i do here:

- 2 big containers have `Heights equally` properties.
- 4 little ones have pin height
- bottom one have `bottom space to superview`

Everything is on UIImageView (i don't know if its matter)

Should I create constraints for container to container? How?

When i change to 3.5 inch display view i'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the blue line from the top of the view to the small container on top left.